# iTerm2 does not show username, machine name, time

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, iterm, zsh

On my new mac machine, I could not do autocomplete for Git when I hit Tab.

So I thought to modify the terminal and found certain things on this [link](http://mikebuss.com/2014/02/02/a-beautiful-productive-terminal-experience/).

I may have messed when I installed iTerm2, Oh-My-ZSH, and Solarised Dark. So now I have nice looking terminal and git autocompletion works.

But in the terminal, the user name, machine name etc does not appear, like it is the in above link.

[image].

The colour scheme is also not great.

Can someone please help me, possibly step-by-step, on how to show these things like in this image [image]

I am very new to Mac and please assume that I know very little about how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you're asking has more to do with the shell than with iTerm. There are numerous tutorials on how to set up your `PROMPT` variable (I use a modified version of [this one](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/)). Since you're using Oh-my-zsh, try looking through the [themes page](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes). There are a variety of styles available (I began with the [af-magic](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes#af-magic) prompt). Once you find a prompt you like, feel free to copy the source from the `.oh-my-zsh/themes` folder to `.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes` and modify the custom version. Details on custom plugins and themes are available [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/5464fe3e4ad02a33243f42bcd8c91a287bc26185/README.markdown#custom-plugins-and-themes).

Comment: Note that Oh-my-zsh will look in `custom/` and `custom/themes/` for files named `$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme` if you set the `ZSH_THEME` variable in your `.zshrc`, so you could name a theme `af-magic_mod.zsh-theme`, place it in the `custom` folder, and set your theme to `ZSH_THEME=af-magic_mod`, just the same way you'd set any of the included themes.

Comment: This worked just like I wanted. But I did not have to copy or move any theme files. All I did was open /zshrc file and set the theme to `ZSH_THEME = ys`.